# C# Design Data Access for Windows Service with LINQ 2 SQL connection

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, data-access-layer

I have a class library setup that is our data access that is using LINQ 2 SQL. It is using the Repository pattern.

Our Repository class has a base class which has our DB Context:

```
    private DataDB db = null;
    public DataDB DBContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (db == null)
                db = new DataDB(ConnectionString);
            return db;
        }
    }
```

Using Structure Map DI we inject a Repository class into our service.

The problem I see is we have a ton of regular classes that have no way to access the data. What we've done to mitigate this (which I'm not sure is correct) is we have  DI Factory helper class which instantiates the service/repo when called:

```
public static class DIFactory
{
    #region Services

    public static IDataService DataService
    {
        get
        {
            return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(typeof(IDataService)) as IDataService;
        }
    }

    #endregion    

    #region Repositories

    public static IRepository Repository
    {
        get
        {
            return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(typeof(IRepository)) as IRepository;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The problem that we are running into when requests (usually high load) are pushed against the Service we see DB errors such as the following:

```
Exception: SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke =>  E[Invalid attempt to call MetaData when reader is closed.
[There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.]
[Invalid attempt to call MetaData when reader is closed.]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar problem, it was related to iterating over the results of a query.  Make sure anytime you are iterating over something that is IEnumerable you do a ToArray() first

```
// Don't do
foreach(var x in items.Where(i => i.value == true))
...

// Do
foreach(var x in items.Where(i => i.value == true).ToArray())
...
```